# Angular 2 Final Routing

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I tried using the latest Angular 2 routing in my project but it seems not to work properly (it always goes on the `path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'`) and i don't understand why. maybe someone is more experienced with it?

this is my `routing.module.ts`:

```
    export const appRoutes: Routes = [{
  path: 'dashboard',
  component: DashboardComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: ':status',
      component: StatusComponent
    },
    {
      path: ':history',
      component: HistoryComponent
    },
    {
      path: ':documentation',
      component: DocumentationComponent
    }]
},
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

which also includes the imports of all components and `import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';`

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
import {routing} from './routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...,],
        imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing
      ],
      directives: ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

and finally the html - app.component.html

```
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
```

one example link in the sidebar

```
    <a [routerLink]="['dashboard/status']">Link</a>
```

sidebar and navbar are shown. also the links seem to be right (hover shows localhost:4200/dashboard/...) but clicking does only redirect to the dashboard.

Comment: Remove the colon (:) in the status path

Comment: removed the `:`but the console throws this error `Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'StatusComponent'`

Comment: then import { StatusComponent }  from './status.component' and add it into declarations in app.module.ts

Comment: it is already importet and declarated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fBTzOB5Alqjebx8fAcBb?p=preview)

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: DashboardComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'status',
      component: StatusComponent
    }]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Import component in ng-module >

`import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';`

2. In ng-module also add this code >

   `RouterModule.forRoot([
     { path: 'othersales', component: OthersalesComponent },
     { path: 'prebooking', component: PrebookingComponent },
   ])`
3. add this app.component in template  : `<a routerLink="/othersales"></a>
     <a routerLink="/prebooking"></a>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>`